# ignoring No data available (61) errors with rsync

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

Is there a way to suppress a warning where the origin changes during the `rsync`?

```
$ rsync --archive server::somemodule/ /dest/dir
rsync: read errors mapping "/somefile" (in somemodule): No data available (61)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1532) [generator=3.0.6]
```

indeed, `somefile` changed during the `rsync` run, but I don't care, I want this error to be ignored. For instance `find` has -`ignore_readdir_race` flag, is there something similar with `rsync`?